# bxSlider 4.1.2 - combining 2 slides

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have 1 bxSlider on my page, showing 1 slide at a time.  My slides are text (quotes) with no images.  I have one quote that is very short, and no matter where I put it, it gets combined with the slide in front or behind it, and the carousel stops.

I've got a jsfiddle that demonstrates this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ktpmm5/8qx8fryf/6/

I've tried putting the options in single quotes, like this:

```
autoControls: 'true',
speed: '500',
pause:'500'
```

And having the options with no quotes.  Neither seems to matter.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8qx8fryf/11/

**CSS:**

```
ul{height:100%}

ul li{height:100%}
```